# RHEL: syntax errors with bash script

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, login, mysql

I was tasked to do a bash script that can audit logins in mysql.
If you activate the `general_log` option in `/etc/my.cnf`, you can register all the activity that mysql does and it get write (in my case) in `/var/lib/mysql/localhost.log`.
If i `cat` it, i get this line:

```
2018-11-18T12:39:46.622298Z     5 Connect   Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

So, with that in mind, I made this grep syntax (change the variables to actual numbers and it works!):

```
grep "$year"-"$month"-"$day" /var/lib/mysql/localhost.log | grep Connect | grep -v denied
```

```
grep "$year"-"$month"-"$day" /var/lib/mysql/localhost.log | grep Connect | grep denied
```

I also made a grep instruction that counts how many of these logins are made.

```
grep "$year"-"$month"-"$day" /var/lib/mysql/localhost.log | grep Connect | grep -cv denied
```

```
grep "$year"-"$month"-"$day" /var/lib/mysql/localhost.log | grep Connect | grep -c denied
```

They all work and, AFAIK they are technically correct (spellchecked!).

But I need to bake them into a script so I can take variables from the user and put them into a proper script, but I can't make them work so far: I'm getting the error you can see below when `bash` tries to read the first variable.

The code so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Year input: "
read -r year
    if [[ $year -gt 2020 ]];
    then
        echo "Incorrect year input."
        exit 1
    else
        echo "Month input: "
        read -r month
            if [[ $month -gt 12 ]];
            then
                echo "Incorrect month input."
                exit 1
            else
                echo "Day input: "
                read -r day
                    if [[ $day -gt 31 ]];
                    then
                        echo "Incorrect day input."
                        exit 1
                    else
                        grep "$year"-"$month"-"$day" /var/lib/mysql/localhost.log | grep Connect | grep -v denied
                        logbien=$(grep "$year"-"$month"-"$day" /var/lib/mysql/localhost.log | grep Connect | grep -cv denied)
                        echo "Correct logins: "echo "$logbien" | wc -1 " times."
                        echo ''
                        grep "$year"-"$month"-"$day" /var/lib/mysql/localhost.log | grep Connect | grep denied
                        logmal=$(grep "$year"-"$month"-"$day" /var/lib/mysql/localhost.log | grep Connect | grep -c denied)
                        echo "Incorrect logins: "echo "$logmal" | wc -1 " times."
                    fi
            fi
    fi
exit 0
```

The error I get (original: image 1 below):

```
[root@localhost ~]# sh /medla/sf_compartida/two.sh
Year input:
2018
': not a valid identifiersh: line 3: read: `year
/media/sf_compartida/two.s: line 34: syntax error: unexpected end of file
[root@localhost ~]#
```

#### Edit

New code:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -r -p "Enter the date (YYYY-mm-dd): " date
if ! date=$(date -d "$date" "+%Y-%m-%d")
    then
        echo "Error: invalid date" >&2
        exit 1
fi
year=${date%%-*}
if [[ $year -gt 2020 ]]
    then 
        echo "invalid year" >&2
        exit 1
        else
        grep "$date" /var/lib/mysql/localhost.log | grep Connect | grep -v denied
        logbien=$(grep "$date" /var/lib/mysql/localhost.log | grep Connect | grep -cv denied)
        echo "Correct logins: "echo "$logbien" | wc -1" times."
        echo ''
        grep "$date" /var/lib/mysql/localhost.log | grep Connect | grep denied
        logmal=$(grep "$date" /var/lib/mysql/localhost.log | grep Connect | grep -c denied)
        echo "Incorrect logins: "echo "$logmal" | wc -1" times."
fi
```

The error I get (original: image 2 below):

```
[root@localhost ~]# sh /media/sf_compartida/two2.sh
Enter the date (YYYY-mm-dd): 2018-11-20
': not a valid identifier.sh: line 2: read: `date
/media/sf compartida/two2.sh: line 9: syntax error in conditional expression
'media/sf_compartida/two2.sh: line 9: syntax error near `]]
'media/sf_compartida/two2.sh: line 9: `if [[ $year -gt 2020 ]]
[root@localhost ~]#
```

---

Error 1 - image:
[image]

Error 2 - image:
[image]

Comment: https://www.shellcheck.net is a good resource for syntax checking shell scripts. You don't have any glaring errors here: you could improve your quoting and command substitution (as pointed out by https://www.shellcheck.net). The main problem with the **output** is that `logbien` and `logmal` contain the grep output which is newline-separated lines. If you want the **number** of good logins, you need to count those lines: `n_bien=$(echo "$logbien" | wc -l)`

Comment: You may also want to run your script as `(export LC_MESSAGES=C; ./your_script)` to report the actual error messages in English.

Comment: I hope you don't have a user called "denied" :-)

Comment: @glennjackman i updated the code with the much appreciated corrections, but i still get the "end of file syntax error" and now i am even more lost than before. Care to check it out again? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you please edit your question, adding the exact command that you run and that gives you that error, *and* the actual text of the error? Your script has issues, but with `bash` on Linux it does give no "end of file" errors. Therefore it's hard to formulate an exhaustive answer.

Comment: @fra-san thanks for pointing the lack of error messages, i just edited the post and added them. And i'd like to know every issue you can see so i can fix it or at least address it. Much appreciated!

Comment: Well, first thing: run your script as `bash path/to/script` (instead of `sh`). You are using some bash-specific syntax - as `[[` - and there is no point in (potentially) invoking a different shell. The actual behavior of `sh` depends on your specific environment (e.g. is it a link to `bash` or something else?).

Comment: The `: not an identifier` lines are the key. You have a carriage return character at the end of one or more of your `read` lines. Get rid of them in an editor. They might be displayed as `^M`.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick i tried to identify the cr iin Word (yes) but i only found the ¶, standard LF. That's what you meant earlier?

Comment: @fra-san i did use bash instead of sh, but same errors. Should i use another extension?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick i tried vi and nano. In vi, as i tried to right-arrow the first `read` and reaching the end of `year`, there was nothing. Same with the other `read`s in the script. In nano, just the line jump; if i tried to delete, the next line would come up where the carriage return was. No luck there :(.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick if i put a semicolon at the end of the read, i get: `/media/sf_compartida/two.sh: line 3: $'\r': command not found`. Is that relevant? just trying things.

Comment: Looks like you definitely have CR (\r) in there. Remove that semicolon, then run `dos2unix < two.sh > twofixed.sh` and see if that new script still has those problems.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick it worked, WOAH. I don't know what that program did but it worked. Now i have plans to put it into a menu, so i can get even more points. Thanks! love ya

Comment: If you are using `bash`-specific syntax, there is no point in invoking a different shell. Yet, doing it might often work, because on many systems `sh` is just a link to `bash`, but beware that `bash`'s behavior may change when invoked as `sh`). Anyway, as we have seen, this is not relevant here.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but a bit of code review: I would offer this to improve your date entry: get the user to enter the date at once, and use the `date` command to validate and normalize the user's input.

```
read -r -p "Enter the date (YYYY-mm-dd): " date
if ! date=$(date -d "$date" "+%Y-%m-%d"); then
    echo "Error: invalid date" >&2
    exit 1
fi
year=${date%%-*}
if [[ $year -gt 2020 ]]; then echo "invalid year" >&2; exit 1; fi

# then: grep "$date" logfile ...
```

Comment: i appreciate that revision! it looks much more cleaner than my initial solution, no doubt. But i still get a lot of error messages. I used the shellcheck and it found no errors whatsoever. I'll add the new code in the post. Thanks!